# Plotting four surfaces with different constraints in one plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I generated the plot shown below using this code:

```
ContourPlot3D[
  {x^2 + y^2 == 2.4, 
   x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 1,
   x^2 + y^2 + (-Sqrt[4.76] + z)^2 == 2.4,
   x^2 + y^2 == .5^2},
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10},
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.65]]
```

[image]

But what I want to do is create this:

```
equation1 = x^2 + y^2 == 2.4
constraint1 = -0.5 - Sqrt[4.76] <= z <= -Sqrt[4.76]

equation2 = x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 1
constraint2 = - Sqrt[4.76] <= z <= Sqrt[4.76]

equation3 = x^2 + y^2 + (-Sqrt[4.76] + z)^2 == 2.4
constraint3 = Sqrt[4.76] <= z <= Sqrt[5.51]

equation4 = x^2 + y^2 == .5^2
constraint4 = Sqrt[5.51] <= z <= Sqrt[5.51] + 1.5
```

I want to plot the surfaces with the constraints given above, so I can get the figure I designed to print in 3D. I'm really confused about how to integrate the constraints in the plot. Any tips?

Comment: [It does not look like something 3D-printable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oMEz.png)...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
equation1 = x^2 + y^2 == 2.4;
constraint1 = -0.5 - Sqrt[4.76] <= z <= -Sqrt[4.76];
equation2 = x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 1;
constraint2 = -Sqrt[4.76] <= z <= Sqrt[4.76];
equation3 = x^2 + y^2 + (-Sqrt[4.76] + z)^2 == 2.4;
constraint3 = Sqrt[4.76] <= z <= Sqrt[5.51];
equation4 = x^2 + y^2 == .5^2;
constraint4 = Sqrt[5.51] <= z <= Sqrt[5.51] + 1.5;

g1 = ContourPlot3D[
   Evaluate[equation1], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, 
    constraint1[[1]], constraint1[[3]]}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[.65]];

g2 = ContourPlot3D[
   Evaluate[equation2], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, 
    constraint2[[1]], constraint2[[3]]}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[.65]];

g3 = ContourPlot3D[
   Evaluate[equation3], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, 
    constraint3[[1]], constraint3[[3]]}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[.65]];

g4 = ContourPlot3D[
   Evaluate[equation4], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, 
    constraint4[[1]], constraint4[[3]]}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[.65]];

Show[{g1, g2, g3, g4}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image]